# Empty CSS file when running NPM RUN DEV

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix

So I have external CSS under resources/assets/css.
I also included all the ccs in the webpack.mix.js

```
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/transaction-listing.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printRemReport.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printAR.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printAR2.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printOCR.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printCodingSheet.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/pritnIEMOP_CSR.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/pritnPayementDetails.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/pritnSummaryofCollection.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss("resources/assets/css/fitall/printAging.css", "public/css");
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css', 'public/css/bootstrap');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-vue.css', 'public/css/bootstrap');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/bootstrap/kidlat.css', 'public/css/bootstrap');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printFitAllSL.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printFitAllAging.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/print-fitSoaDetails.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/print-fitSoa.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/print-fitSoaDetails2.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/print-fitSoaCS.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/print-mfrcrr.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/print-mfrcrrDetails.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printLandscape.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printZoom.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printRecon.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/printSl.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/dashboard.css', 'public/css');
mix.postCss('resources/assets/css/fitall/print-reconPaymentDetails.css', 'public/css');
```

but for some reason when i run NPM RUN DEV the generated ccs file in the public/css folder is empty. all the file was generated but the content inside the css file is empty and this is what shows when running NPM RUN DEV

[image]

This is working previously but now its not.